# Ack method throwing an exception after a long running task is over

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

I need to consume JSON messages from Rabbitmq and perform long-running tasks on each of these Jsons. I am using a job-queue mechanism with maxsize 1 and the channel pre-fetch count as 1 so that my code has to handle one message from Rabbitmq at a time. This part seems to be working. The code seems to fail when in the same thread from which the pika connection was made and then the long-running task is run,  when the ack callback is called, the code is failing in an internal library throwing up error:

> required argument is not an integer.

Have discovered that the error occurs when encode function in an internal library is called. It throws an error when it appends '>Q' string with the delivery_tag. Not sure what this string is though.  The following is the piece of code where it fails:

```
def encode(self): 
  pieces = list()
  pieces.append(struct.pack('>Q', self.delivery_tag))
```

My ack method and the code block where the callback is defined are as follows:

```
def __ack_message(self, delivery_tag, ack):
    print("Inside the __ack_message function")
    if self.channel.is_open:
        try:
             if ack:
                  self.channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag)
             else:
                  self.channel.basic_nack(delivery_tag, requeue=False)
        except Exception as e:
             self.channel.basic_nack(delivery_tag, requeue=False)
             print("Failure inside __ack_message consumer.py report: {}".format(e), "error")
             pass
   else:
        pass

def do_work(self, ch, delivery_tag, body):
    thread_id = threading.get_ident()
    print(f'Thread id:{thread_id} Delivery tag: {delivery_tag} Message body: {body}')
    # long-running work begins here
    print(f"I am inside the message_consume")
    if body != b'':
        message = json.loads(body)
    self.slave_object.push_to_job_queue(self.connection, message)

    cb = functools.partial(self.__ack_message, ch, delivery_tag)
    ch.connection.add_callback_threadsafe(cb)

def on_message(self, ch, method_frame, _header_frame, body, args):
    print("Inside on_message function")
    thrds = args
    delivery_tag = method_frame.delivery_tag
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.do_work, args=(ch, delivery_tag, body))
    t.start()
    thrds.append(t)
```

Comment: The code fails when the following line inside __ack_message is called:
`If ack:
        self.channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag)`

Comment: It looks like the __ack_message() function declares delivery_tag and ack as parameters, but in the functools.partial you're supplying it the channel (as delivery_tag) and delivery_tag (as ack). The code fails — I think — because basic_ack expects an int as an argument, but you're effectively calling it with a channel.